# Can I use double negative in the following structure: "not that..."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

We are taught in schools that in English, double negatives are not so welcome, which is hard to understand because of my own language in which it is quite common.

Nevertheless, I come across some sentences which use double negatives from time to time and it's starting to cloud my mind... (e.g. : I ain't need no sleep)

And here's a new example I've just read : "I think you should set this pic as your profile picture. **Not that** the current one **isn't** nice, but this one is better."

So, is this okay to say this in this example?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"It's not that the current one is bad, but this one is better," would please grammatical purist.  However, the sentence as you have it is acceptable to me as long as you begin it with a subject and verb (It is or It's).  Otherwise it is not a sentence.